# Azure AD application - List subscription with role assignment

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-subscription

I'm new to Azure. I created an Azure AD application and gave it reader role assignments in several subscriptions - and I want to list those subscriptions dynamically

I need an API to list all the subscriptions which my application has a role assignment on, but I can't find a way to do it. any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below REST API method to list the subscriptions

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01
```

**Reference**: [Subscriptions - List - REST API (Azure Resource Management) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list)

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The API you would want to call is [`Subscriptions - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) which will give you the list of all subscriptions the caller has access to.